# Is there any way to simplify a radical expression with index 3?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a very simple question. Is there any formula or tricks to simply this expression?
$$\sqrt[3]{a+bc},$$
where a and b are rational number and $c$ is irrational. For example $\sqrt[3]{26+15\sqrt{3}}= 2 + \sqrt{3}$.

We can't simplify this expression for all $a$, $b$ and $c$, which means there is no general formula IMO. I can simplify radicals with index 2 by solving an equation, e.g. for simplifying $\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}}$, I always find two number that their sum of squares equals $3$ and their product equals $\sqrt{2}$, according to $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$.  Those 2 numbers are $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$. As a result:
$$\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{2}} = 1 + \sqrt{2}.$$
But I have no idea to do the same thing with index 3.

Comment: See [*The cube root of a binomial surd*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2972529) by Arthur C. Johnson (1913) **AND** [*Finding the cube root of binomial quadratic surds*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2688084) by Kaidy Tan (1966) **AND** the google search ["cube root" + "binomial surd"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cube+root%22+%22binomial+surd%22&filter=0) **AND** the google search ["cube root" + "quadratic surd"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cube+root%22+%22quadratic+surd%22&filter=0).